# compiling source from android externel folder

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-source, openssh

I have AOSP android-4.0.1_r1 downloaded from Android site.
http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

There is OpenSSH folder and source inside /external folder.

When I compiled the entire aosp for emulator, I am not able to ssh executable created in android out folder for emulator.

Is there a way how I can compile OpenSSH from android's external folder?

- Ruchik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look into the Android.mk file of OpenSSH you'll find the following line:

```
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
```

This means that the module will be include into a build if the module name is listed in the appropriate make file (for instance, in a `build/target/product/core.mk`)

Comment: Then you should accept the answer as an appropriate one. This is how StackOverflow works.